# Why do I need to manually login to some SE sites seperately, when I have already logged in through SO?

Tags: support, login, accounts

I have logged on to Stack Overflow. Then under the Stack Exchange drop down I click on Android Enthusiasts. The page loads and asks me to refresh in order to login, but when I click on Unix & Linux or Tor it, is asking me to login manually. There is no refresh to login again as shown in Android Enthusiasts.

[image]

In the above image as you can  see I have a profile on Unix & Linux as well as Android Enthusiasts, Stack Overflow, and Tor. The problem is that if I click on the Linux or the Tor site I have to manually login to the site as in the below image[image]

Comment: Is the stackauth page blocked? What does the [network login test page](http://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) say?

Comment: @Oded Success!

All necessary browser features are enabled and functioning for network-wide automatic login.

Comment: Have you manually logged out of the sites?

Comment: No and when I return I simply get the refresh option

Comment: The refresh option? You mean the white bar that tells you that you have been automatically logged in?

Comment: yes exactly I never logout of the site

Comment: Do you clear your cookies? Is your ISP changing your IP address frequently?

Comment: Its a static IP address and I clear cookies only when the temp internet files exceed the max storage amount(250Mb) allocated or there is some problem with the browser. The latest version of cookies get updated automatically

Comment: I am confused - if these sites automatically log you in when you visit them, when exactly do you have to manually log in?

Comment: Not all sites automatically log me in.For Tor,Unix &Linux it is not showing the white refresh bar

Comment: OK. Try deleting all cookies for it, see if that helps.

Comment: FWIW, i was about to ask the same question as user285oo6, above; does the design of StackExchange mean that our SO logons work for ALL StackExchange websites? or, do some StackExchange websites have unique credentials?

Comment: The same thing happens to me too. I have to manually log into Unix site, Webmasters, Programmers, Area51, and many others. It's fuckin' weird. There have been atleast 50 times where I wanted to answer somebody's question, but decided not to because _yet again_ I was asked to sign in when I was already signed in and already a member of that website.

Comment: I was just about to ask a similar question.  The "Rep" drop down on Travel said someone/something had recently given me some points on a question I wrote three years ago on StackOverflow.  I clicked that and went to the question, but I was not logged in on that site.  That's the first time since I linked accounts (long ago) that my login was not preserved when clicking one of those dropdowns.